# with rxjs and angular, Is it necessary to unsubscribe for the subscriptions that happen only once in app component's onInit method?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Since the ngOnInit is called only once in app's life, when I make a subscription to an observable in ngOnInit, is it still necessary to unsubscribe?

Is it possible for the app to create memory leak for the browser after the app/tab is closed?

Comment: After the tab/browser is closed? No. However, there are observables that keeps emitting data until you explicitly call unsubscribe or it errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from \`Subscription\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Comment: am i missing something?  why do people think this question is related to other random component subscription?  i am talking about the app root.  the only time you unsubscribe is when the app is closed.  and if the app is closed, do we still care about memory leak?

Comment: Have a read of my pattern for Angular state management here https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: In most cases you shouldn't have to unsubscribe as described in #1 here https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0 . But might as well unsubscribe to guard against any edge cases...

Answer (score 2):

The Short answers are:

1) Always

2) Yes

[This article](https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) describes very well why we should unsubscribe from all observables, and how to do it in an effective way in angular.

If you are Subscribing on the `ngOnInit` function you should be unsubscribing via `ngOnDestroy`.

I usually create an `unsubscribe` Subject, and call `next()` on it on `ngOnDestroy`. I would have all my subscriptions with a `takeUntil(unsubscribe)`.

This is what I mean:

```
unsubscribe = new Subject();

(...)

subscribeTo() {
   this.myService.getAll().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
    ).subscribe(data => this.localData = data);
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: This is not the best approach. use as follows: `const subscriptions = new Subscription;`

Comment: And then `this.subscriptions.add(something.subscribe(...) )`

Comment: `ngOnDestroy() { this.subscriptions.unsubscribe() }`

Comment: So the above mentioned code is in the app root.  Let's say I don't have the ngOnDestroy block.  I close my app (close the browser or the tab).  Now there will be a memory leak in Chrome or other browser?  And this will slow down other web applications using that browser?

Comment: potentially; "closed" apps can remain running on the background. So if you have enough memory liking the phone could get quite slow after some usage of your app in a browser.

Comment: I am not convinced the ngOnDestroy is run in that scenario.

Comment: it is run when you implement `OnDestroy` as per angular API: https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

My answer is YES.

If this happen only one time in the `OnInit` lifecycle then you use `take(1)` is enough.

Example:

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.observableData$ = this.myService.getAll().pipe(take(1));
}
```

The benefits are:

1. no `unsubscribe`
2. no `ngOnDestroy`
3. less code, less bug

However, I suggested you another way to handle data by reactive programming in [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/angular-and-rxjs-patterns-use-reactive-programming-to-compose-and-manage-data-in-angular-apps-2e0c4ce7a39c?source=friends_link&sk=be4b4ec70b1564b9802d1e5afac805a8). Because `subscribe` to get data is not right. We just use `subscribe` to do callback for another stuff (not data).

Comment: take is for handling emission.  take(1) means you care about the first emission only.  but i am interested in all emissions.  my point is, when the app/browser tab is closed, is the browser still listening to the emissions?  the app certainly doesn't care about memory leak when it's closed...

Comment: I think it depends on the case. `take(1)` in case of call API to get data. In case of `subscribe` the form change or other things then you can use `takeUntil`. YES. But what if you do not close the tab?

Comment: if you don't close the tab then ngOnDestroy won't be called

Comment: Yes. But in case of `take(1)` we do not need wait for `OnDestroy`. In case of `takeUntil` then need wait `OnDestroy` I sure that your site is not only have one page right? Because in my opinion, if your app have only one or two pages, you do not need to handle this one.

Comment: take(1) will not be unsubscribed if the observable has not emitted yet and you have an orphaned subscription. Use takeUntil.

Answer (score 0):

I personally never subscribe an use the async pipe to manage subscriptions for me.

```
data$ = this.service.getData();
```

and in the template

```
<ng-conatainer *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
  {{ data | json }}
</ng-conatainer>
```

No need for any subscriptions.